# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') ..i can not fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**Repeatedly showing this problem...**

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "questions":
      action.value.forEach(question => {
        question.options.forEach(option => {
          option.checked = false
        })
      })

      return action.value
    case "answer":
      const questions = _.cloneDeep(state)
      questions[action.questionID].options[action.optionIndex].checked =
        action.value

      return questions
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Which `forEach` is the issue? There are two of them. Please share the complete error message and any code stacktrace for it. Should the `"questions"` case be using the state in some way, like returning it? It also appears to be doing some object mutation which is generally frowned upon in React.

Comment: either `action.value` or `question.options` doesn't have the forEach method - make sure they do before using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "questions":
      (action.value || []).forEach(question => {
        (question.options || []).forEach(option => {
          option.checked = false
        })
      })

      return action.value
    case "answer":
      const questions = _.cloneDeep(state)
      questions[action.questionID].options[action.optionIndex].checked =
        action.value

      return questions
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check if the value exists or not in action.value

```
        const reducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "questions":
if(action && action.value && action.value.length){
              action.value.forEach(question => {
                question.options.forEach(option => {
                  option.checked = false
                })
              })
    
          return action.value
}
        case "answer":
          const questions = _.cloneDeep(state)
          questions[action.questionID].options[action.optionIndex].checked =
            action.value
    
          return questions
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

If you are using forEach then array should have length.

```
if(action && action.value && action.value.length){
action.value.forEach(question => console.log(question))
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).